# Space needed for Just Dance 2014 on PS4

Tags: ps4, just-dance-2014

I'm really inclined to buy a Playstation Camera and the Just Dance 2014 game on the Playstation 4.

However I really wanted to know how much space it would require to play this game.

My couch is 1,2m (~4ft) away from the TV, but I can push it away and gain more space for a total of 1,8m (6ft). I would like to play a two player game with this setup. This space will have to account for, at least a little of, leg movement back and forward (for dance moves).

Will I be able to play comfortably with this setup? I could not find any source with the actual measurements, so I'm counting on your experience.

Comment: Were you able to play comfortably Vargas?

Comment: I haven't bought the camera/game so, no!

Answer (score 1):

1.5-1.8m should be enough for 2 players.